# Drupal website was hacked?

Tags: users

What is the hack that can cause my Drual website to be blank, without showing any message error.. Not be able even I enter .../users, -> blank. It was absolutely brilliantly showing fine.

If you want to see this Drupal website URL, go ahead:

http://fightforhongkongdemocracy.net

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close, this is more a question of general LAMP server administration than it is Drupal. Plus it's a really broad question that can't have definitive answer without access to your server to diagnose the problem. You might find a more receptive audience over at StackOverflow or ServerFault than here.

Comment: sounds like a WSOD - what was the last thing you changed?

Answer (score 2):

There is a guide on drupal.org with multiple troubleshooting methods to resolve white screens with no ouputs: https://www.drupal.org/node/482956

Comment: I was told from my provider that module/theme is corrupted. Does this may cause a WSOD? I discovered also an intruder was coming inside as unauthorized user that I do not know he may have the power to change theme?

Comment: Anything that causes php errors can potentially cause a WSOD, for example I was tweaking a panel earlier and referenced a non-existant template file causing a WSOD.

So yes, a module or theme having issues can cause a WSOD. What does the watchdog table say has happened recently?

Also, if an intruder has access to the database they have unlimited power in drupal and can do anything, they can grant themselves superuser privelages, adjust modules, settings, etc. directly from the database.

What version do you use for Drupal?

Answer (score -1):

It is not finding it on the server. Reboot the server and try again quickly.